# Is there a site where PDFs of all airlines related to passenger rules/regulations are uploaded?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airlines, regulations

I was going through [What is a stopover?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70778/what-is-a-stopover) and one of the comments shared [What is a stopover?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70778/what-is-a-stopover#comment151597_70779) talks about http://www.britishairways.com/assets/pdfs/information/legal/International-Passenger-Rules-Tariff-part-1.pdf .

While this seems to be interesting to itself, this is related only to BA. Is there a site or an online-resource where people could find such rules and regulations of different airlines at one glance or download pdf's rather than going to the airline and trying to hunt to get the required information.

Answer (score 8):

The document you link to references the [Airline Tariff Publishing Company](http://www.atpco.net/). Legacy carriers (as opposed to low cost carriers) file their tariffs, fares, and multitudinous [other data](http://www.atpco.net/products) with ATPCO where it can be obtained for a not-insignficant fee. If you are looking for airline's conditions of carriage, it would be easier and cheaper to look at the airline's own website. If you wish to look at fare rules, they can be found by using [matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com). Fare data and other airport and airline data can be found on [ExpertFlyer](http://www.expertflyer.com/) which is a subscription site providing web access to [GDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Distribution_System) data. It has a free trial period.

Comment: I wonder if anyone at Open Data SE would be interested in compiling / organising this data!

Comment: @TimMalone, any progress on the Open Data SE  on this. If need be, can re-ask it there.

Comment: @shirish Yeah definitely feel free to ask there - I didn't have time to look into it unfortunately. Just make sure you read the rules there to make sure it fits (I'm not 100% familiar with them), and definitely link to this question too.